# Typescript multiple sequential awaits not blocking

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to figure out how to get multiple back-to-back await calls to occur in sequential order. Here's my setup:

- typescript 2.5.2

  - transpiling to es5
  - using libs `es2017` and `dom` in tsconfig
- node.js 8.6
- deploying to a docker container running in minikube 0.22.2

Here's the problem code. It's running a query against postgresql using the node pg package. I based it off of the example code https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions#a-pooled-client-with-async-await.

```
import { Client, Pool } from 'pg';

// An existing client connection can be passed in so that the calling code
// can manage a transaction. If none is provided, a new connection is
// retrieved from the connection pool.
async function query(
  connPool: Pool,
  querystr: string,
  params: (number | string)[],
  client?: Client
): Promise<any[]> {
  let result;
  let conn: Client = client;
  if (conn) {
    result = await conn.query(querystr, params);
  }
  else {
    conn = await connPool.connect();
    result = await conn.query(querystr, params);
    conn.release();
  }
  return result.rows;
}
```

And I'm calling the query() funtion from another file, like so:

```
const results = await query(myPool, 'SELECT * FROM my_table');
doOtherThing(results);
```

Based on every source code example I've seen, I expect it to behave this way:

- call made to query()
- line `conn = await connPool.connect();` blocks until a connection is retrieved from the pool
- line `result = await conn.query(querystr, params);` blocks until the results of the query are retrieved
- line `return result.rows;` returns results to the calling code
- the calling code receives the records from the database
- doOtherThing() is called

However, it's executing in this order:

- call made to query()
- line `conn = await connPool.connect();` returns immediately
- the calling code receives `undefined` in results
- doOtherThing() is called
- line `result = await conn.query(querystr, params);` returns immediately, to nowhere
- line `return result.rows;` results are returned to nowhere

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong? Am I completely misguided on the right way to use async/await?

Comment: Mine works just fine. How do you create ```connPool```? What version of node are you using?  What is your ```target``` in ```tsconfig.json``` set to?

Comment: @Wainage:  I create the connection pool with `connPool = new Pool(settings)`, where settings is an object with the postgres connection configuration.  Using node 8.6.  Target in tsconfig is es5.  The query() code shown above is implemented in a separate package that I import (which I also wrote), so it's located in node_modules/ of the project where I call the function.

Comment: I updated the code example for clarity, which better illustrates what is happening.  I have a statement `doOtherThing(results);` that occurs after the call to query().  I wrote this assuming that this statement wouldn't be called until all asynchronous awaited functions within the query() function had successfully resolved their promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The expected behavior laid out in the question is correct.

In between the statement `const results = await query(myPool, 'SELECT * FROM my_table');` and the actual function was another function with the same name `query()`. This other function acted as a pass-through to the implementation of the `query()` function that I included in the original post. This function in the middle didn't return anything, which caused the unexpected behavior.